# How to send HashMap with in GET query in java

Tags: java, php, android, hashmap, retrofit

I'm a beginner in Android. I'm trying to communicate using Retrofit. The problems I faced were as follows. You are trying to send multiple queries to the server as follows: Other queries fly well, but the hashmaps do not deliver normally. Please help me to solve the problem that I've encountered.Help Me!

> android retrofit.java code

```
 @GET("product_option.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> request_detail_category_product_information1(

            @Query("option") String filter_option,
            @Query("page") String page,
            @Query("fitme") String fitme,
            @Query("body_information") Map<String, String>HashMap

    );
```

> php code

```
    $option = $_GET['option'];
    $now_page = $_GET['page'];
    $fitme = $_GET['fitme'];
    $body_information = $_GET['body_information']; 

    if($body_information){

        $shoulder = $body_information['shoulder'];

        $chest =  $body_information['chest'];

        $waist = $body_information['waist'];

        $hip =  $body_information['hip'];

        $thigh =  $body_information['thigh'];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple query params with `@QueryMap` annotation instead of `@Query`.

```
@QueryMap Map<String, String> queryParams
```

Then you can access it in php.

```
$_GET['shoulder'];
$_GET['chest'];
```

[example](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-add-multiple-query-parameter-with-querymap)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I haven't solved it yet. Could you show me another solution by looking at my example?

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. Well, but my code above has been modified a little, too. I have to get a key value of $body_information = $_GET['body_information']; as I see it. May I ask for help with this, too? :-)

Comment: I did not try to combine '@Query' and '@QueryMap', but you can try it. You can also add all the query params into one map. Don't think about body_information as object with fields, you have request with query params and all the params are same level. Nothing is grouped or encapsulated. Maybe some frameworks can handle this object oriented query params, but I'm not php developer to answer this.